# disk space limitation when creating war file

Tags: linux, shell, war

I have 1 GB disk space limitation for hosting my app and I have used 700MB of it.

However I want to create a war file from a directory which is so big (around 600MB) using this command :

```
jar -cvf ROOT.war folderPath
```

that's why I encounter quota limitation and I can't do the following.

I'm looking for a way to delete the folder content when It's applying the archive to conserve disk space

take note that I can't install zip tool in my ssh shell ~

Comment: Why not download the folder and create the war file on your local machine?

Comment: because the upload is a nightmare

Comment: @davidgiga1993 that is the worst solution ~

Comment: Ask your provider for another GB temporarily.

Comment: @DanFromGermany that is not a solution, Its like I'm eliminating the question

Comment: Create the file in pieces? `jar -cvf ROOT.war <some files>; rm <some files>; jar -uvf ROOT.war <more files>; rm <more files>; ....`?

Answer (score 0):

The code works on test directories, but test it first anyway, as it **deletes** files.  It's not very efficient.

Assumptions: 300MB free space, in which to destructively compress a 600MB *folderpath* directory.  None of the files are too big -- if any  file in *folderpath* is 300MB or larger, this will fail.

Notes:  If the '*$out*' file exists, do nothing.  First `find` pipes the file list to `while`, if '*$out*' doesn't exist in the loop, create it, don't update it -- if it *does* exist, just update it.  Each pass adds one more file, then deletes it unless that file is a directory.  After the loop finishes delete the empty directories too.

```
unset U ; in=folderpath ; out=ROOT.war ; \
[ -f $out ] || ( find $in | \
while read a ; do \
    [ -f $out ] && U=u ; \
    jar -cvf$U $out "$a" || { echo "Fail, stopping..." ; exit 1 ; } \
    rm -d "$a" 2> /dev/null ; \
done ; rm -rd $in ; )
```